# ElementTree doesn't find root correctly

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've a xml file as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gexf xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" version="1.2">
    <graph mode="static" defaultedgetype="directed">
        <nodes>
            <node id="0" label="Hello" />
            <node id="1" label="Word" />
        </nodes>
        <edges>
            <edge id="0" source="0" target="1" />
        </edges>
    </graph>
</gexf>
```

When I run the following code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import xml.sax

with open('basic.gexf', 'r') as xml_file:
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

root.tag
```

I get the following output:

```
'{http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft}gexf'
```

Shouldn't it be 'gexf' only ?

My aim is to get attributes of the graph&nodes&edges. How can I do it w/o manually supplying the namespace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft}` represents the namespace (`xmlns`) for `gexf`.

The value you're seeing is what is expected.

Comment: How can I just get the 'gexf' then ? Without dealing with the namespaces.

Comment: @SpiderRico, I don't think there's anything built-in to `ElementTree` to do so. Why do you need it?

Comment: Well how can I parse and do comparisons then ? Don't I need to enter the namespace manually in this case ?

Comment: For say, what do I need to do to get list of nodes in this case?